# Pandera validate get all valid rows

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, pandera

I am trying to use pandera library (I am very new with this) for pandas dataframe validation.
What I want to do is to ignore the rows which are not valid as per the schema.
How can I do that?

for example:
pandera schema looks like below:

```
import pandera as pa
import pandas as pd

schema: pa.DataFrameSchema = pa.DataFrameSchema(columns={
  'Col1': pa.Column(str),
  'Col2': pa.Column(float, checks=pa.Check(lambda x: (0 <= x <= 1)), nullable=True),
})

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({
    "Col1": ["1", "2", "3", nan],
    "Col2": [0.3, 0.4, 5, 0.2],
})
```

What I want to do is when I apply validation on the `df` I get a result:

```
   Col1  Col2
0     1   0.3
1     2   0.4
```

The other rows with error dropped.

Comment: I created and added the pandera tag to this question, so @Prashant, please approve [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30327414) to get the new tag applied to your question.

Answer (score 2):

pandera author here!

Currently you have to use a `try except` block with lazy validation. The `SchemaErrors.failure_cases` df doesn't always have an index in certain cases, like if the column's type is incorrect. The index only applies to checks that produce an index-aligned boolean dataframe/series.

By default the `check_fn` function fed into `pa.Check` should take a pandas Series as input. I fixed your custom check like so:

```python
import pandera as pa
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

schema: pa.DataFrameSchema = pa.DataFrameSchema(columns={
  'Col1': pa.Column(str),
  'Col2': pa.Column(
      float, checks=pa.Check(lambda series: series.between(0, 1)), nullable=True
    ),
})

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({
    "Col1": ["1", "2", "3", np.nan],
    "Col2": [0.3, 0.4, 5, 0.2],
})

try:
    schema(df, lazy=True)
except pa.errors.SchemaErrors as exc:
    filtered_df = df[~df.index.isin(exc.failure_cases["index"])]

print(f"filtered df:\n{filtered_df}")
```

Output:

```
filtered df:
  Col1  Col2
0    1   0.3
1    2   0.4
```

To check value ranges I'd recommend using the built-in [`pa.Check.in_range`](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/methods/pandera.checks.Check.in_range.html#pandera.checks.Check.in_range) check.

In other cases, just be aware of the `element_wise=True` kwarg in [pa.Check](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/pandera.checks.Check.html#pandera.checks.Check), it modifies the expected type signature of the `check_fn` arg.

Comment: how come there isn't an index provided for rows that fail the initial type check? i want to be able to remove those from the dataframe as well

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I heard of Pandera but it looks like a cool library. After a bit of digging around, you can catch the validation error and filter  out the failure indexes:

```py
fail_index = []
try:
    schema.validate(df)
except pa.errors.SchemaError as ex:
    fail_index = ex.failure_cases['index']

clean_df = df[~df.index.isin(fail_index)]
```

Documentation about `SchemaError`: https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/pandera.errors.SchemaError.html#pandera.errors.SchemaError

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried that already but there are two things:
1. SchemaError Exception is caught as soon as first invalid row is encountered.
2. There is a lazy mode as well in validate which throws `pa.errors.SchemaErrors` after validating all rows. But the failure_cases not always contain index. It sometimes is None.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with failure_cases not always having an index - might be a bug (sorry for replying with an answer, I have no reputation).
Here's a minimal reproduction:

```
import pandas, pandera

df = pandas.DataFrame({"c1": ["9"]})
# other checks also fail, e.g.:
# pandera.Column(str, checks=pandera.Check.le(10))
schema = pandera.DataFrameSchema({"c1": pandera.Column(int)})

try:
    schema.validate(df, lazy=True)
except pandera.errors.SchemaErrors as err:
    print(err.failure_cases)
```

Output:

```
  schema_context column           check check_number failure_case index
0         Column     c1  dtype('int64')         None       object  None
```

I would expect the index to be 0 here, not None.  I suspect `pandera.Check`s do something special which doesn't happen for data type mismatch errors or for errors that occur before the `Check` finishes (such as the `TypeError("operator not supported...` you get with the `str` `le` check).